# django fat models: should they make rest requests?

Tags: python, django, model

Some time ago a colleague of mine wrote a method on a model that updated its data over a REST api. At that time, I thought that this kind of thing should be done by a controller (or view in Django's lingo), which should make the request and tell model to update itself, and so I asked her to rewrite that. However, reading more on Django and its "Fat models" approach, I now come to think that it is the model that should do the request after all.

It is a payment system, and the model in question is a Transaction. The REST api that needs to be called is a backend of that payment system that has certain statuses that affect the status of the transaction, and the REST api call is made to check the status of the remote system and to set the status of the Transaction in the local application.

What would you do? Where would you put the API call: the model or a view?

Comment: Unfortunately this is an architecture question that is too open for discussion and the answer depends on many factors. A quick answer though that will be right in most cases is the following: Neither on the model or the view. Calling an external API should be called asynchronously (django-rq or django-celery, you can also check my tutorial for django-rq: https://spapas.github.io/2015/01/27/async-tasks-with-django-rq/) , most probably with a service that will actually create its own models that would capture the request parameters and response (if there was an error etc).

Comment: This bit is done asynchronously most of the time (as a callback from that remote system), but sometimes if it takes too long, the user may press the "refresh" button in the interface, and we will go and check synchronously. This was another consideration for putting this into the view. The callback lives in a view, so it tells a model what it's new status is. The synch handle does the same. Another approach is to ask the Transaction what it's new status is, and then it would go and check that with the remote system. I will look into the tutorials, though )